Why does assignment with the null coalescing operator not compile?
I expected this assignment to work.  It does not.
public class Foo {}

public class Bar {}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo? foo = null;
        Bar? bar = new Bar();
        object? val = foo ?? bar;  // FAIL: Compiler error CS0019
    }
}

The compiler doesn't like the last line.  Complains with this error
error CS0019: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Foo' and 'Bar'
But I've declared a Foo? and a Bar? which are both assignable to a variable of type object?.  If I change it to use an if statement and 4 lines, it works just fine.
        object? val = default;

        if (foo != null)
            val = foo;
        else
            val = bar;

And I did eventually discover that if I put an explicit cast to (object?) in front of the left side, it does compile in one line
    object? val = (object?)foo ?? bar;  // THIS COMPILES

But I still want to understand: Why does the first version not work?  Can the compiler not find the common, nullable type between them?

In answer that was referred the person was trying to assign two incompatible types to var.  It could not have been broken into the if/then/else that I broke mine into without changing it to object? -- which is compatible with either.  Which again begs the question, WHY?  The referred question does not actually explain why other than to say, "you just cannot because the language doesn't let you"   Even the link in there "expressions" section of to the language spec does not explain it.

You can read the language specs for that operator if you want a more formal definition over the type rules.

The very specific steps about the type evaluation of the null-coalescing-expression a ?? b spells it out for me.  Thank you.  Seems very arcane but I'm sure there's a good reason that would take me a week to understand.
